regarding vector of random variables
In my research work I came across the following expression
$P = \underbrace{A_1(\textbf{h}_2^T(n)\cdot \Psi \cdot \textbf{h}_1(n)+A_2h_0(n))}_{Part 1}$ + $w(n)$ ---(1)
where $\textbf{h}_2(n)$ is a $M \times 1$ vector, $\Psi$ is $M \times M $ identity matrix and $\textbf{h}_1(n)$ is a $M \times 1$ vector.
Scalar $h_2(n)$ is given as $h_2(n) = \hat{h}_2+\Phi_{h_2}(n)+h_{2_\epsilon}$, scalar $h_1(n)$ is given as $h_1(n) = \hat{h}_1+\Phi_{h_1}(n)+h_{1_\epsilon}$ and $h_0(n) = \hat{h}_0+\Phi_{h_0}(n)+h_{0_\epsilon}$
Also,
$A_1, A_2$ are constant.
$w(n)$ is additive white Gaussian noise modelled as $\mathcal{C}{N}(0, N_w)$
$\hat{h}_{2}$ and $\hat{h}_{1}$ are complex Gaussian random variables with zero mean and unit variance.
$\Phi_{h_{2}}(n)$ is modelled as zero mean circularly symmetric complex Gaussian (ZMCSCG) i.e., $\mathcal{C}\mathcal{N}(0,(1-\rho_{h_{2}}^{2(n-1)})\sigma^2_{h_{2}})$
$h_{{2}_{\epsilon}}$ is also modelled as ZMCSCG i.e.,  $\mathcal{C}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_{\epsilon_{h_{2}}})$
$\Phi_{h_{1}}(n)$ is modelled as ZMCSCG i.e., $\mathcal{C}\mathcal{N}(0,(1-\rho_{h_{1}}^{2(n-1)})\sigma^2_{h_{1}})$
$h_{{1}_{\epsilon}}$ is also modelled as ZMCSCG i.e.,  $\mathcal{C}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_{\epsilon_{h_{1}}})$
My query is that from (1) I want to write the expression in the form of ratio of variance of Part 1 and $w(n)$, but i am not getting how to proceed with it.
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.
